# page navigation with swipe using data entry forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to teach my self Xamarin Forms. I am trying to make a bowling score card. I want to have a page where you enter the pins and other info for each turn. I want to swipe between each page for example first time up enter your results, second time swipe right to enter that turn.

What kind of control is that? is that a rotator, page viewer, or some other control.

thank you for any guidance.

Comment: look at the CarouselView

Comment: https://medium.com/globant/xamarin-forms-the-latest-carouselview-and-indicatorview-7fef11a5f785